# How to convert the element in a pandas.dataframe to np.float while use pandas.read_csv to read csv file?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, numpy

I have a .csv file, which is an exported output from a software. This .csv file contains a lot of NaNs. I need to analyze the data by reading it into a dataframe, and use `dataframe.fillna(0)` to replace all the NaNs with 0. However, when I use `pandas.read_csv()` to import this .csv file, the type of element in the dataframe is 'str', so `dataframe.fillna(0)` cannot be used. So my question is: how to convert the element as np.float while reading the .csv file?

There is an argument `dtype` for [`pandas.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html), here is the explantion:

```
dtype : Type name or dict of column -> type, default None
Data type for data or columns. E.g. {‘a’: np.float64, ‘b’: np.int32} Use str 
or object to preserve and not interpret dtype. If converters are specified, 
they will be applied INSTEAD of dtype conversion.
```

Any examples of how to use it?

Thank you very much!

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

**UPDATE:**

**Here are several solutions proposed by the answerers:**

(1) from @Jakub. Setting the `na_values=NaN` in `pandas.read_csv()`, so all of the elements in the .csv file can be converted to `np.float` as being read into dataframe.

(2) from @André Christoffer Andersen. After read the .csv file as dataframe. use `pandas.to_numeric` to convert a column of the dataframe into `np.float`. Use a for loop to convert all columns into numeric.

(3) from @ThisGuyCantEven. Use `numpy.loadtxt` to read .csv file into a `numpy.ndarray`. Use the `skiprows` argument to skip the rows with unequal elements. Then use `numpy.nan_to_num()` to convert `nan` to zeros.

Hopefully, it will help following readers!

Comment: You can tell read_csv what the NaN values are with the `na_values` parameter. That should convert those values to np.nan, which you can then replace as usual.

Comment: Thank you very much, @Jakub! It works like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

If you have a new enough pandas version you can also use [pd.to_numeric(...)](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) for this:

```
df['mycol'] = pd.to_numeric(df['mycol'], errors='coerce')
```

And, here is a trick to convert the whole dataframe:

```
for col in df.columns:
    df[col] = pd.to_numeric(df[col], errors='coerce')
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It works well for a series object or single data frame column. Any function to convert the whole data frame?

Comment: @Jundong Sure. See my edit. Just loop over the cols.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use `numpy.loadtxt`? If you want to use pandas because, say, you have mixed data and you want a numeric column as a numpy array, you can always use `df['column'].as_matrix()`, or you can convert the whole data frame if you want.

Comment: Thank you very much! I forgot `numpy.loadtxt`. I just tried it and realized that `numpy.loadtxt` requires each row must have the same amount of elements. For my .csv file, there are first several rows that need to be skipped, which can be done by the argument `skiprows` as well. For the `nan`, it can be converted to 0 by `numpy.nan_to_num`. This could be an alternative method.

Comment: You can also skip columns with the `usecols` argument, however, if you want to skip certain columns specified by an array, you might have to use that array to mask the values in another array containing all of the column indexes.